# Error in socket Node js

Tags: node.js, sockets

I use library net in Node JS for create socket server

All of things is good and very good working.

But it get error sometimes

Error is :
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:581:26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this event triggered while the connection is dead.
did you handle the server-side close event? like this

```
socket.on("close",function(){
 //you can't handle the network operation anymore after this by the socket object
})
```

the heartbeat measure is necessary in socket project.